# Como monitorar a mudança de um campo input type text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Preciso monitorar a mudança do conteúdo de um campo tipo text, a função que uso é essa:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#nome").on("keyup change click focus", function() {
    $(".classenome").val($(this).val());
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="nome" value="">
<input type="text" id="duble" class="classenome" value="">
```

Tentei todos os eventos acima, quando o usuario digita diretamente no campo "nome" funciona de boa por causa do keyup, mas se ele preenche por aquela lista de histórico que o navegador sugere a função só funciona quando ele sai do campo por causa do evento "change".

Existe algum outro evento que monitore caso o valor/texto seja do historico?

Estou pensando que vou ter que desenvolver um timer pra isso, mas não queria.

Comment: Testa juntar o evento `input`.

Comment: Matou é isso mesmo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usa o evento [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input), testei no Chrome e Firefox agora e funciona quando o Browser faz auto complete.

```
var input = document.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener('input', function() {
  console.log('input', this.value);
});
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mjn0kskb/