# Como colocar hífen entre os caracteres de uma string

Tags: javascript, regex

Separar os caracteres de uma string com hífen em Python funciona perfeitamente desse jeito:

```
import re

regex = r"\B(?=(.{1}))"

test_str = "Pêssego"

subst = "-"

result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0)

if result:
    print (result) // P-ê-s-s-e-g-o
```

Mas em JavaScript não:

```js
const regex = /\B(?=(.{1}))/g;
const str = `Pêssego`;
const subst = `-`;

const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result); // Pês-s-e-g-o
```

Devo acrescentar algo? Tirar algo? Qual a diferença entre os dois? Existe alguma outra forma de separar uma string com hífens em em tempo real em um campo de entrada?

Comment: `console.log("Pêssego".split("").join("-"))`

Comment: Existe uma forma sem regex de fazer: `'Pêssego'.split('').join('-');`

Comment: Ou ainda utilizar o protocolo de iteração implementado pelas strings: `[...'Pêssego']`. :-)

Comment: @AugustoVasques Bem pensado. Usando esse método, fazer a alteração enquanto digita seria possivel? Em regex eu teria algo assim em uma função keyup: ```this.value = this.value.replace(/ /g,''); var string = this.value; this.value = string.replace(/\B(?=(.{1}))/g, "-");```

Comment: Só pra constar, a regex poderia ser apenas `\B(?=.)`, pois o `{1}` é redundante: de modo geral `(qualquer coisa){1}` é o mesmo que `(qualquer coisa)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apesar da expressão ser a mesma, você acabou de perceber uma característica fundamental de regex: elas não funcionam exatamente da mesma forma em todas as linguagens/*engines*/ferramentas, pois apesar do funcionamento "básico" ser o mesmo (ou, no máximo, similar), cada uma implementa de um jeito e como diz o ditado, "o diabo está nos detalhes".

Em Python, por *default*, regex são compatíveis com Unicode (podemos dizer, de forma **bem** resumida, que elas vão "além do ASCII"). Isso quer dizer que [atalhos](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) como `\w`, `\b` e até mesmo o `.` trabalham com [Unicode *code points*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/394834/112052), e consideram letras acentuadas e de outros alfabetos.

Mas no JavaScript, muitos atalhos trabalham apenas com ASCII, não considerando caracteres acentudados. [É o caso do `\w`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#regular_expression_and_unicode_characters) (que significa "*letras de `a` a `z` (maiúsculas e minúsculas), dígitos de `0` a `9` e o caractere `_`*", sem considerar acentos). E como os atalhos `\b` e `\B` indicam posições da string levando em conta se antes e depois têm ou não caracteres alfanuméricos (ver explicação detalhada [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/420487/112052)), estes também não consideram letras acentuadas (em Python, o `\w` considera qualquer letra de qualquer alfabeto, incluindo as acentuadas, por isso o `\b` e `\B` também funcionam nestes casos).

---

Nos comentários foram dadas alternativas para fazer isso sem regex, mas **tem um detalhe**: o resultado só será igual se a string tiver apenas caracteres alfanuméricos. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```js
function test(str) {
    const regex = /\B(?=(.{1}))/g;
    const subst = '-';
    console.log(`------------\nTestando: '${str}'`);
    // usando sua regex
    console.log(`regex: ${str.replace(regex, subst)}`);
    // usando split (conforme sugerido nos comentários)
    console.log(`split: ${str.split("").join("-")}`);
}

test('Pêssego');
test('Oi, tudo bem?');
```

O resultado é:

```
------------
Testando: 'Pêssego'
regex: Pês-s-e-g-o
split: P-ê-s-s-e-g-o
------------
Testando: 'Oi, tudo bem?'
regex: O-i,- t-u-d-o b-e-m?
split: O-i-,- -t-u-d-o- -b-e-m-?
```

Repare que quando há caracteres não-alfanuméricos (como espaços e sinais de pontuação), sua regex só coloca o hífen entre dois alfanuméricos ou entre dois não-alfanuméricos (repare que foi colocado entre a vírgula e o espaço que há logo depois dela), pois o `\B` indica exatamente isso: uma posição da string na qual os caracteres antes e depois são do mesmo "tipo" (ou ambos são alfanuméricos, ou ambos não são). Mas quando há apenas um espaço separando 2 palavras, não é colocado o hífen entre elas (o mesmo vale para o final: antes do `?` não é colocado o hífen, pois esta é uma posição em que antes há uma letra e depois não).

Mas usando `split`, é colocado um hífen entre todos os caracteres, sem considerar se eles são alfanuméricos ou não.

---

Enfim, se você quer colocar o hífen entre **todos** os caracteres da string, independente de serem ou não alfanuméricos, então use `split`/`join` (ou use o *spread operator*: `[...str].join("-")`).

Mas se a ideia é colocar o hífen apenas entre as letras das palavras, aí tem que mudar um pouco a solução.

Se quer mesmo usar regex, uma opção é usar [*Unicode property escapes*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes) - mas veja antes [se seu *browser*/ambiente é compatível](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#browser_compatibility) (no momento em que escrevo, somente o IE não é):

```js
const regex = /(\p{L})(?=\p{L})/gu;
const str = 'Pêssego';
const subst = '$1-';
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result); // P-ê-s-s-e-g-o

console.log('Oi, tudo bem?'.replace(regex, subst)); // O-i, t-u-d-o b-e-m?
```

No caso, `\p{L}` é qualquer letra que esteja definida pelo Unicode (incluindo letras acentuadas e de outros alfabetos). A ideia é pegar uma letra (`(\p{L})`), desde que esteja seguida por outra letra (`(?=\p{L})`).

A primeira letra está [entre parênteses para formar um grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) (e como é o primeiro par de parênteses, então é o grupo 1). E na string de substituição eu uso `$1` para pegar o que foi capturado no grupo 1, e coloco o hífen em seguida.

Vale notar o uso da [*flag* `u`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#advanced_searching_with_flags) (habilita o "modo Unicode"), sem a qual os *Unicode property escapes* não funcionam adequadamente.

Com isso os casos em que há mais de uma palavra são tratados corretamente: repare como na string `'Oi, tudo bem?'` os hífens só são colocados entre as letras (mas novamente, se a intenção é colocar o hífen entre todos os caracteres, eu escolheria usar `split`/`join` por ser - na minha opinião - mais simples).

---

Outra opção é usar [*lookbehind*](http://regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```js
const regex = /(?<=\p{L})(?=\p{L})/gu;
const str = 'Pêssego';
const subst = '-';
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result); // P-ê-s-s-e-g-o
console.log('Oi, tudo bem?'.replace(regex, subst)); // O-i, t-u-d-o b-e-m?
```

Assim, eu pego as posições da string que tem uma letra antes (indicado pelo *lookbehind* `(?<=\p{L})`) e uma letra depois (indicado pelo *lookahead* `(?=\p{L})`), e insiro o hífen nestas posições. No fundo, é uma forma de simular o `\B` (mas considerando apenas o caso em que ambos são letras - lembre-se que `\B` também considera os casos em que ambos não são alfanuméricos).

---

Se quiser limitar apenas para caracteres do português, também pode usar algo como:

```
const regex = /([a-záàâãéèêíïóôõöúç])(?=[a-záàâãéèêíïóôõöúç])/gi;
```

Ou alguma das outras opções listadas [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15738/112052).

---

Por fim, vale reforçar que há outra diferença. Mesmo se o `\B` funcionasse para caracteres acentuados, ainda daria diferença para o caso em que há dois ou mais caracteres não-alfanuméricos seguidos:

```js
const str = 'abc...';
const regex1 = /(\p{L})(?=\p{L})/gu;
const regex2 = /\B(?=.)/g;
console.log(str.replace(regex1, "$1-")); // a-b-c...
console.log(str.replace(regex2, "-"));   // a-b-c.-.-.
```

No primeiro caso a regex só colocará o hífen entre duas letras (pois eu verifico explicitamente por letras - `\p{L}`), enquanto que o `\B` verifica posições da string em que os caracteres antes e depois são do mesmo "tipo" (ambos alfanuméricos ou ambos não-alfanuméricos). Por isso ele também insere o hífen entre dois caracteres `.` e isso dá diferença no resultado final.

---

Sobre a questão de "*mudar o campo em tempo real*", pode dar uma olhada [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/134443/112052) e [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/574941)

Comment: Wow, não imaginava que tem havia tamanha discrepância entre os dois. Muito obrigado, foi de grande ajuda. E sobre o tempo real, consegui implementar com as duas e a melhor opção foi com o regex. Se puder indicar um bom livro ou videos para aprender regex ficaria muito grato!

Comment: @Lordepina Sobre regex, dois sites que eu gosto bastante são [esse](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) e [esse](https://www.rexegg.com). E livros, eu recomendo [esse](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596528126.do) e [esse](https://www.amazon.com/Regular-Expressions-Cookbook-Solutions-Programming/dp/1449319432)